# how to find the shortest products of randomly removed complete product?

Tags: python, math

how to find the shortest products of randomly removed complete product?

(2, 2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2, 2)
(2, 1, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 2, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1)

above is the product of [(1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2)], length of product = 1, this is also called a complete product
elements in total: 16

now randomly a few of them get removed.
(2, 2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2, 1)  -- removed
(2, 2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2, 2)  -- removed
(2, 1, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 2, 1) -- removed
(1, 2, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 2, 1)  -- removed
(1, 1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1)

now we have:
(2, 2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1)

way 1
product of
[(1,), (1,2), (1,), (1,2)]  + [(1,2), (2,), (2,), (2,)] + [(2,), (1,2), (1,), (1,2)]
add
(1, 1, 2, 2)
(2, 1, 2, 1)
the length of product = 5, so we shorten 12 to 5

way 2
we have anther way to shorten it:
product of
[(1,2), (1,2), (1,), (1,)]  + [(1,2), (2,), (1,2), (2,)] + [(1,), (1,), (1,2), (2,)]
add
(2, 1, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 1, 2)
the length of product = 5, so we shorten 12 to 5

these two ways have different products but the same length.

So there should exist a best shortening way that could shorten 12 to minimal.

In general, we have a complete product, and randomly some of its element are removed,  we want to find the smallest product in length or the best way to shorten it.

Any thoughts or information would help.

Comment: Interesting question, but a discussion topic like this is off topic for SO. Try cs.stackexchange.com instead. There might be an algorithms stackexchange forum as well, I don't remember for sure.

Comment: This is about math and computer science, how could this is off topic?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions, other stackexchange forums (cs, etc.) are for problems which need discussion. Somewhere on SO there's a guide as to what's considered an appropriate question for this forum; sorry, I don't know where it is without looking.